# How to override behavior of base abstract class?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, nunit, moq

**How do I override base class behavior when testing the derived class?**

```
public abstract BaseController
{
    public virtual bool DoStuff(){};
}

public class UsageController : BaseController
{
    public string MethodToTest()
    {
       if (base.DoStuff())
          {return "yes";}
       return "no";
    }
}
```

I would like to setup the return value for **DoStuff()**, is this possible?

```
[Test]
public void Returns_Yes_When_True()
{
     var sut = new UsageController();
     //how would I setup the behavior of DoStuff?
     Assert.That(sut.MethodToTest()=="yes");
}
```

Comment: Note that `MethodToTest()` returns a string and thus `==true` will always be false.

Comment: @DStanley thanks! corrected.

Comment: Inherit from the UsageController, override DoStuff() method and test its behaviour on your child class

Comment: @user1681317 this would work if DoStuff() were a virtual method in UsageController, but it is actually a virtual method in UsageController's base class called BaseController

Comment: I don't think this is possible.

Comment: @MeggieLuski Why can't UsageController override DoStuff()? I don't understand the issue you're having.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I override base class behavior when testing the derived class?

By actually overriding it. Provided that `UsageController` is not sealed.

```
public class TestController : UsageController {
    public override bool DoStuff(){ return true; };
}
```

Inherit from the derived class and use the stub in the test

```
[Test]
public void Returns_Yes_When_True() {
    //Arrange
    var expected = "yes";
    var sut = new TestController();
    //Act
    var actual = sut.MethodToTest();
    //Assert
    Assert.That(expected == actual);
}
```

UPDATE:

It passes when you remove `base` and call the instance method

```
public class UsageController : BaseController {
    public string MethodToTest() {
       if (DoStuff())
          {return "yes";}
       return "no";
    }
}
```

which makes sense since if i remember correctly guidelines advised that `base` should be called within overrides.

[base (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfw7t1ce.aspx)

Comment: this would work if DoStuff() were a virtual method in UsageController, but it is actually a virtual method in UsageController's base class called BaseController

Comment: Wouldn't it also work to just override DoStuff() in UsageController without having to inherit from UsageController?

Comment: The scenario is for a unit test so the OP wanted to be able to change the result of DoStuff for the purposes of the test case.